# Is it possible to use Javascript to push data collected from a form into a formatted html file for download?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As the title suggests, I am wondering if it is possible to use Javascript to grab information entered in a form and pushing that information into a formatted html file for download after clicking submit?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, it helped to answer some questions that I had.

Comment: "[Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)" should help with part.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this SERVER SIDE. Use php, not JS